# Is there something like Acegi for PHP?

Tags: php, spring-security

In Java world, [Acegi](http://www.acegisecurity.org/) is a powerful security framework based on Spring that allows you to simply manage authentication and authorization. AFAIU, it supports OpenID, and Facebook Connect, LDAP, NTLM, Kerberos, etc. via Grails. If you are interested how it works, take a look at diagrams in this [tutorial](http://www.tfo-eservices.eu/wb_tutorials/media/SpringAcegiTutorial/HTML/SpringAcegiTutorial-1_1-html.html)

Anyway, this is all cool, but I'm developing a PHP application (using CodeIgniter, FWIW) and I'm looking for something similar for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acegi security is great.

Combination of [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html) + [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) components from **Zend Framework** gives me a decent substition of acegi security in PHP.

You can use just a few components from the Zend framework and still work in your CodeIgniter environment though.

**Updated:**
Zend_Auth provides the following authentication methods:

- Digest realm
- LDAP
- OpenId
- InfoCard

Comment: Looks useful for some intranet applications, but it's still far behind Acegi. Only LDAP is supported, while Acegi also supports OpenID, Facebook Connect, NTLM, Kerberos and more. I still have to use RPX.

Comment: Answer has been updated. Zend_Auth can handle OpenID authentication. IMO, it is the most mature solution in PHP stack at the moment, BUT it is not a full clone of acegi security though.

Answer (score 2):

you should have a look at Flow3 framework ... it has been inspired by Spring a lot, having a similar security mechanism like Sprig Security (or Acegi, if you want) ...

greetz

back2dos