# how to make more secure backend and urls with zend?

Tags: php, security, magento, zend-framework

I am trying to make a backend with Zend, I was wondering if there is any way to make it more secure, any special framework to use? I read I could use :[Is there something like Acegi for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106625/is-there-something-like-acegi-for-php)

how secure is this? I have used spring security before, and it always worked great, is there something similar to work on zend? are those options ok?

I also checked magento, and for example, urls are like this

```
index/key/8555b140ead18e6c004037e5c82d6478/
```

that is the url if I want to enter to the catalogo, and so on, they only change the key instead change the url for a controller name, that key is a route for security reasons? or is dynamically created by the framework? (as far as I know , they use Zend).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That key is generated depending on the route you are accessing and a random string that changes each time the session is restarted.
So for each login you get a different session key.
The downside of this approach is that you can't give to someone else an admin url and tell him "Hey! look here", because they session key is different.

If you want to check how this feature is implemented, take a look at the following code in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::getUrl()`:

```
$_route = $this->getRouteName() ? $this->getRouteName() : '*';
$_controller = $this->getControllerName() ? $this->getControllerName() : $this->getDefaultControllerName();
$_action = $this->getActionName() ? $this->getActionName() : $this->getDefaultActionName();

if ($cacheSecretKey) {
    $secret = array(self::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME => "\${$_controller}/{$_action}\$");
}
else {
   $secret = array(self::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME => $this->getSecretKey($_controller, $_action));
}
```

This is the code that generates the secret key.  Going deeper in `getSecretKey` method you will see:

```
public function getSecretKey($controller = null, $action = null)
{
    $salt = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

    $p = explode('/', trim($this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo(), '/'));
    if (!$controller) {
        $controller = !empty($p[1]) ? $p[1] : $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    }
    if (!$action) {
        $action = !empty($p[2]) ? $p[2] : $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    }

    $secret = $controller . $action . $salt;
    return Mage::helper('core')->getHash($secret);
}
```

So the secret key is a hash build from the controller name, the action name and a `$salt` generated this way `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();`

The `getFormKey` method looks like this (one value per session):

```
public function getFormKey()
{
    if (!$this->getData('_form_key')) {
        $this->setData('_form_key', Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16));
    }
    return $this->getData('_form_key');
}
```